# How to set context in DialogFlow java client v2

Tags: dialogflow-es, api-ai

Setting the context with dialogflow javaclient v1 is well explained.
v1 maven dependency being :

> ai.api.libai.samples
>         libai-samples      1.6.12

I am trying to use the v2 of javaclient of google-cloud-dataflow.

> com.google.cloud
>               google-cloud-dialogflow
>               0.45.0-alpha

There are no good examples of how to set the context for an intent.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out their [Github repo](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/tree/master/samples) but specifically [ContextManagement.java](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/dialogflow/ContextManagement.java)